# How to put conditions in char array?

Tags: c++, arrays, char

Hello so i have this char array which needs to have some conditions in case 1 and 2. v[0] must be between 0 and 19 and v[0]+v[1] must be <= 19. I cannot figure it out how to do it. Also in case 1 if i have n=2 and the numbers are 2 and 3 i need to get 2 3 4.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char v[20];
    int pc, functie, n, i, loop;
    do {
        cout << "Este pornit calculatorul? (0/1) ";
        cin >> pc;
    } while (pc != 1);

loop:
    cout << "Ce functie selectati? 1-4 ";
    cin >> functie;
    switch (functie) {
    case 1:
        cout << "Citire din memorie" << endl;
        cout << "Cate numere cititi din memorie: ";
        cin >> n;
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            cout << "v[" << i << "]=" << v[i] << " ";
            cout << endl;
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        cout << "Scriere in memorie" << endl;
        cout << "Cate numere scrieti ";
        cin >> n;
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            cout << "v[" << i << "]= ";
            cin >> v[i];
        }
        break;
    case 3:
        cout << "Golirea memoriei";
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            v[i] = '\0';
        cout << endl;
        break;
    case 4:
        cout << "Oprirea calculatorului";
        exit(0);
        break;
    default:
        cout << "Nu ati selectat nici o functie";
    }
    goto loop;
}
```

Comment: `do {
        cin >> pc;
    } while (pc != 1);` should not be in a MCVE, `pc == 1` at the end of the loop and pc is not even used.

Comment: `while (true)` or `for(;;)` can replace your `goto`